# Visual Studio 2017 inserting 2 spaces instead of what is set in settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 I want tabs not spaces but it's inserting 2 spaces instead of a tab? I changed the setting why is it not working?

[image: asdf]

Comment: Do you have a .editorconfig file in your solution directory or above?  That always trumps the VS editor settings.

Comment: where is that located?

Comment: It would be a file on disk.  If you don't have one, the next thing I'd check is the tab settings for the specific language you're using.

Comment: What possible reason would the settings you attempt to change not actually do anything? That's very bad design and makes absolutely no sense.